# How to objects multiple times while building with a clearmake makefile

Tags: makefile

I am creating a master build target in my Makefile. I have a target like "all_images"

all_images: fast_image   slow_image

fast_image: clean_objects dep_1 dep_2 dep_3

slow_image: clean_objects dep_1 dep_2 dep_3

fast_image has some other conditions in the makefile that cause it to have fast_image in the final image names and slow_image has the same thing in its names..

I want to clean in between the build of fast and slow (delete all of the .o files, obviously not the final images) but when i do this, clean_objects doesn't happen the 2nd time because its already happened during fast_image.

Before you say "You shouldn't have to clean because the slow_image should rebuild everything that changed", our particular environment has a very complicated makefile that does code generation, clearmake that does some gnu_make kick offs, and other things. I must clean the objects between, is there a way to force a dependency that already happened to happen again?  I know i can go all over the place and delete all of the .o files manually, but the clean_objects target already goes off and has a bunch of dependencies that does all sorts of complicated object deletions and I wont want to do all that manually if I don't have to.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are many ways to do this but first thing that comes to my mind is to make two separate targets `clean_fast_image_objects` and `clean_slow_image_objects` then have both of those just call a defined makefile function that runs the commands that `clean_objects` currently does.

Comment: I did exactly what you suggested and that is working fine...  Thanks!